# E1101: Module 'mysql.connector' has no 'errors' member (no-member)

Tags: python, github-actions, pylint

I have written a python program and it's working fine on my computer, but when I'm trying to lint it with pylint and have this error: `E1101: Module 'mysql.connector' has no 'errors' member (no-member)`

I have pieces of code like this in my code:

```
try: 
    ...
except mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError:
    ...
```

To catch mysql errors and I repead It works fine on my computer but is an error at GitHun Actions pipeline.
Here is pipeline by the way:

```
name: Pylint

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.9", "3.10"]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@v3
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        pip install pylint
    - name: Analysing the code with pylint
      run: |
        pylint $(git ls-files '*.py')
```

What do I miss?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve]. You'll then probably also see where the bug lies.

Comment: See pylint documentation about no-member https://pylint.pycqa.org/en/latest/user_guide/messages/error/no-member.html#no-member-e1101